# SharePoint 2013 Content By Search Disable ASCII Sorting

Tags: 2013, search-results, content-search-web-part

I am building a Content By Search web part that read data from a custom list with one column "Title". I have updated the search schema to mark the title column as sortable and now I can choose the title to sort by however the search results is always sorted by ASCII like [0-9A-Za-z] so if I have the following items

- Hossam
- A
- a

The search results will be

- A
- Hossam
- a

So I need your support on what I can do to make my search results like below

- A
- a
- Hossam

I have found the following link that is talking about the same issue with SharePoint 2010 FAST search but no hints about how to fix it on SharePoint 2013

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pasen/archive/2011/03/08/case-insensitive-sort-order-in-fast-search-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have ended up by maintaining another field with all upper case letters (Which was fine for my business), and used the new field for sorting the results.